# Sign/give someone your autograph

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

People like getting star's autographs,so once a star refused to sign autograph as he didn't like signing the autographs. So what sounds more natural:

> Sorry but I don't sign autograph.

Or

> Sorry I don't give my autograph.

So what sounds more natural "sign" or "give" or are both of them equally natural?..

Comment: I think "give" sound more natural than "sign".

Comment: http://www.freecollocation.com/search?word=autograph You can use this website to check which words are frequently found next to the queried word. Also, check learner's dictionaries because they often have these as well (https://www.ldoceonline.com/, https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/). In this case you can say *I don't sign/give autographs*.

Comment: Ringo Starr decided to stop: search for `ringo autographs` and you will see many newspaper headlines "ringo too busy/refuses to sign autographs" and "stopped signing autographs", certainly you will also find "get/give autographs".

Answer (score 1):

A native might likely say

> No autographs.

or

> I don't **do** autographs.

or

> I'm not giving you my autograph!

though I've never been asked for my autograph.

Answer (score -3):

You can say only "to give an autograph"

For the reason of this use, look at the [graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sign_VERB%20autographs%2C%20give_VERB%20autographs&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csign_VERB%20autographs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgive_VERB%20autographs%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: So would you use: Sorry but I don't give my autograph.

Comment: I won't give my autograph. Or: I don't give my autographs.

Comment: Your Ngrams graph compares **Sign** (capital S) with **give** (lower case g). Using lower case for both terms shows that **sign** is *much* more common.